# Firestore cloud functions: Dynamic keys in nested maps

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore I have an document consisting of UIDs which each contain a nested map of key value pairs. I need to add a new entry to the document with Firebase cloud functions and I'm using Typescript. I can't find a way to set dynamic key to nested field. With static keys it works:

```js
firestoredocument.set({
    thisIsStatic : {
       nestedField: "value" 
   }
}, {merge: true})
```

But with dynamic key it will output the dynamic key to Firestore without any data inside it (dynamicValue: {})

```js
var dynamic = "dynamicValue"

firestoredocument.set({
   [dynamic] : {
       nestedField: "value" 
   }
}, {merge: true})
```

Printing the input object will output; {"dynamicValue":{"nestedField":"value"}} but in the document the value of dynamicField is empty.

I have also tried to use .update() instead of .set() with same results.

Inputting nested Map to the functions outputs error:

Unhandled error Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Input is not a plain JavaScript object.

Edit:

Per suggestion I also tried:

```js
const dynamic = 'dynamicValue'
const str1 = JSON.stringify({staticValue : { nestedField: "value" }})
const str2 = JSON.stringify({[dynamic] : { nestedField: "value" }})
functions.logger.log(str1)
functions.logger.log(str2)
  

await admin.firestore().doc('mydocumentpath')
  .set(JSON.parse(str1))

await admin.firestore().doc('mydocumentpath')
  .update(JSON.parse(str2))
```

This will log out:

```
{"staticValue":{"nestedField":"value"}}
{"dynamicValue":{"nestedField":"value"}}
```

But the Firestore document will look like regardless of str1 and str2 update order:

```
staticValue: {
    nestedField: "value"
}

dynamicValue: {}
```

Comment: Did you try storing it in a variable and then pass it? Like this, `var data = {};` `data[dynamic] = { nestedField: "value"  }` and then pass to  `firestoredocument.set(data, {merge: true})`

Comment: I have tried setting each field individually like you suggested but it didn't change anything. This problem really seems weird to me as I can log with functions.logger.log both static and dynamic style and the print is identical but the dynamic still shows empty value in Firestore.

Comment: Try to convert your object to a json string and the string to a valid object by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({[dynamic] : { nestedField: "value" }}))` maybe the firestore library can't handle typescript objects