# Adding nested map values to firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty new to javascript and also firestore. I'm trying to add some values to the database which are generated from an input form.

I have the following values taken from the form:

Ingredient: Corriander
Measure: Cups
Amount: 1

So I wanted to have the structure:

ingredients: {ingredient: {Corriander: {amount:1, type:'cups'}}}

However, when I try and use my variables:

ingredients: {ingredient: {ing: {amount:am, type:mea}}}

The amount and measure values work fine, but the ingredient value enters into the database as "ing" and not the value "Corriander".

Here is my javascript:

```
    const generateTemplate = (ing, am, mea) => {
  const html = `

    <li class="list-group-item"><span>${am} </span><span>${mea}</span> of <span>${ing}</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i></li>

  `;
  list.innerHTML += html;


 // console.log(ing);
  const newIng = {
    //user: userID,
    //name: recipeName,
    ingredients: {ingredient: {ing: {amount:am, type:mea}}},
    //created_at: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(now),
  };
console.log(newIng);

        db.collection("recipes")
 .add(newIng)
.then(() => {
  console.log("ing added");
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

};
```

Comment: I managed to solve this by putting [ ] around the variable:

 ingredients: {ingredient: {[ing]: {amount:am, type:mea}}}

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add the firebase DB structure, to understand the entire picture of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were looking for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) in Javascript objects. That allows you to put an expression in brackets `[]`, that will be computed and used as the property name.

```
const propertyName = "name"

const myObj = {}
myObj[propertyName] = "Username"

console.log(myObject)
// {name: "Username"}
```

Answer (score 1):

With help from this post:
[Firestore cloud functions: Dynamic keys in nested maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454831/firestore-cloud-functions-dynamic-keys-in-nested-maps)

I used [ ] around the value:
{ingredient: {[ing]: {amount:am, type:mea}}}

Hurrah!